# Xamarin - MediaPlugin save to album won't work under iOS

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I am using the [MediaPlugin](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/MediaPlugin) for Xamarin Forms and try to save the taken picture into a specific album in the gallary, this works fine uner Android but not under iOS. I also added the requierd permissions (`NSPhotoLibraryAddUsageDescription` and `NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription`) into the Info.plist file.

```
file = await CrossMedia.Current.TakePhotoAsync(new StoreCameraMediaOptions()
{
      CompressionQuality= _defaultCompression,
      SaveToAlbum = true,
      Directory = "mynewAlbum",
      Name = Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + ".jpg",
      DefaultCamera = CameraDevice.Rear,
      SaveMetaData = true,
      Location = loc,

});
```

Any suggestions what I could do to make it working or is this not even possible with the MediaPlugin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at this issue. [MediaPlugin GitHub](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/MediaPlugin/issues/149)

Looks like it will be possible after James or someone else will implement.